# show multiple showlink in jqgrid in single cell

Tags: jqgrid

Hi I have developed the jqgrid in my mvc web application by using jquery  in .net. I am able to show hyperlink to call action from controller. But My form has some download links. how to configure download link and show multiple download link in single cell ? these links are in variable in numbers so can not keep columns for each link. so best way to put all links in single cell. I am using C# as code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to create two links in one cell. The implementation could be a little different depend on the form in which you return the data to the jqGrid from the server (depend on j). The third parameter of the custom formatter `rowObject` contain the data of the row in the for in which you send it from the server.

In some situation you will be need to define [Custom Unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) also which are used to get the data back from the formatting cell. For example if you allow sorting of the column (if you don't use `sortable:false`) the data from the custom formatted column must be read and compared. In the case [Custom Unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) is needed.

If you will have problem with the implementation you should append your question with more information,

Comment: I can get the different values in array from controller which to be shown as hyperlink in single cell of JQGrid. But facing trouble in formatting the grid as I want to create a hyperlink for each array item and then call controller method for each links. Please advise me how can I achieve that.

Comment: @tom: You can salve the problem using of custom formatter or using [formatter: "dynamicLink"](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935) (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17236943/315935) too). You can post new question where you describe the problem on some test data.