# Adding links to jQgrid and open in new window

Tags: json, url, jqgrid, parameters, xpages

I have this jqgrid definition and I'm trying to open the selected document in a new Window.

My final urls should like these:

```
http://localhost/XPagesSortableSearchResults.nsf/xPerson.xsp?documentId=9D93E80306A7AA88802572580072717A&action=openDocument
```

and also I need to generate this type of url:

```
http://localhost/XPagesSortableSearchResults.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=9D93E80306A7AA88802572580072717&action=openDocument


$().ready(function(){
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'./xGrid7.xsp/peoplejson',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['InternetAddress','#','Name','OfficeCountry'],
        colModel:[                              
            {name:'InternetAddress',index:'InternetAddress', width:200},
            {name:'@position',index:'@position', width:50,sorttype:'int'},
            {name:'$17',index:'$17', width:200},
            {name:'OfficeCountry',
                   width:200,
                   formatter:editLinkFmatter
                  // formatter:'showlink',
                  // formatoptions:{ baseLinkUrl:'xPerson.xsp',addParam: '&action=openDocument', idName:'documentId'}
            }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: '@unid',
            root: function (obj) {
                  if ($.isArray(obj)) {
                       return obj;
                  }
                  if ($.isArray(obj.items)) {
                    return obj.items;
                  }
                  return [];
                     },
             page: function () { return 1; },
             total: function () { return 1; },
             records: function (obj) {
                    if ($.isArray(obj)) {
                        return obj.length;
                    }
                    if ($.isArray(obj.items)) {
                        return obj.items.length;
                    }
                    return 0;
            }
        },
        caption: "JSON Example",
        height: 500,
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        rowNum: 50, 
        rowList: [50, 100, 500, 1000],
        pager: '#pager2'
        }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, defaultSearch: 'cn', searchOnEnter: false});
```

Note my Json object looks like this and I'm not using the documentId I need on my url as part of my ColModel; the value I need is @unid

```
        [
      {
          "@entryid":"1-B933790B1DC265ED8025725800728CC5",
          "@unid":"B933790B1DC265ED8025725800728CC5",
          "@noteid":"1E76E",
          "@position":"1",
          "@read":true,
          "@siblings":40000,
          "@form":"Person",
          "$17":"Aaron, Adam",
          "InternetAddress":"consurgo@compleo.net",
          "OfficeCountry":"Namibia"
      },
      {
          "@entryid":"2-9D93E80306A7AA88802572580072717A",
          "@unid":"9D93E80306A7AA88802572580072717A",
          "@noteid":"19376",
          "@position":"2",
          "@read":true,
          "@siblings":40000,
          "@form":"Person",
          "$17":"Aaron, Dave",
          "InternetAddress":"gratia@incito.co.uk",
          "OfficeCountry":"Brazil"
      },
      {
          "@entryid":"3-FAFA753960DB587A80257258007287CF",
          "@unid":"FAFA753960DB587A80257258007287CF",
          "@noteid":"1D842",
          "@position":"3",
          "@read":true,
          "@siblings":40000,
          "@form":"Person",
          "$17":"Aaron, Donnie",
          "InternetAddress":"vociferor@nequities.net",
          "OfficeCountry":"Algeria"
      }
]
```

So far I make it work using:

```
  {name:'OfficeCountry',
               width:200,                                      
               formatter:'showlink',
               formatoptions:{ baseLinkUrl:'xPerson.xsp',addParam: '&action=openDocument', idName:'documentId'}
    }
```

but I need to open it in a new window

I also tried with formatter:editLinkFmatter

```
function editLinkFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href='./" + rowObject[2] + "' class='requestlink'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
    //return "<a href='./documentId=" + rowObject.@unid + "' >Click here</a>";
    //return "<a href='./documentId=" + options.idName + "&action=OpenDocument'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```

and I can't use rowObject.@unid because the node name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you should just use `target="_blank"`attribute in the `<a>` (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target)). The standard 'showlink' formatter  supports `target` attribute.

As the alternative to the custom formatter you can use 'dynamicLink' formatter (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935)). You can download the last version of `jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js` from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins).

**UPDATED**: To assess the property with the name `@unid` you can use syntax `rowObject["@unid"]`. So the `editLinkFmatter` can be like

```
function editLinkFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href='?documentId=" + rowObject["@unid"] +
        "&action=OpenDocument' class='requestlink'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```

or better like

```
function editLinkFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href='?" +
        $.param({
            documentId: rowObject["@unid"],
            action: 'OpenDocument'
        }) + "' class='requestlink'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thank @Oleg, I'm clear with _blank attribute; the problem is I can't get the row value for @unid item. I tried rowObject.@unid and I get "can't convert AttributeName to string" because the @ on my item name; if I try for example rowObject.InternetAddress works fine.  I also tried rowObject[2] with no joy that is why I'm using `{name:'OfficeCountry',                    width:200,                    formatter:'showlink',                   formatoptions:{ baseLinkUrl:'xPerson.xsp',addParam: '&action=openDocument', idName:'documentId'}             } ` and works fine but not opening in a new window

Comment: @PSolano: Ohh! It's not a real problem. You can just use another syntax: `rowObject["@unid"]`. You can use this it the property has some special characters, like '@' or ' ' (space) for example: `rowObject["my property with spaces"]`.

Comment: You are the men definitely. Worked like a charm. I'm a Notes Developer and I want to use this grid control on Domino applications and I haven't seen anything outside integrating jqGrid and Notes. Still have lot of questions and I'm moving slowly but with good progress. Tks again.

Comment: @PSolano: You are welcome! I never developed for Domino (only a little for Exchange), but I know that it allows many kind of customization. If you'll become more questions I'll try to help you. Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks; I'll post some questions today if you have some time to take a look.Thanks in advance