# pass a Cell value in JQGrid as a parameter

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a JQGrid as below.

```
{ name: 'Name', index: 'Name', align: 'left', title:false },
{ name: 'User', index: 'User', align: 'left', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'/APP/URL.htm', addParam: '&userName=' +100}, title:false },
```

in this at the end am passing a number 100. that is hardcoded. the second line is a hyperlink. On click of that am redirecting to other page and passing a value. but i need to send the value present in Name column. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to solve your problem will be the usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) instead of [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `showlink`.

If you have column in `colModel` which has `name: "Name"` then you need to create link with `src` constructed as `"/APP/URL.htm?userName=<Name>"` you can do about following

```js
{ name: 'Name', title: false },
{ name: 'User', title: false,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<a src="/APP/URL.htm?userName=' + rowObject.Name + '">' +
            cellvalue + "</a>";
    }}
```

The code of formatter depends on which format of data you used to fill the grid and whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. It can be that in your case `rowObject` will be array and to access `Name` you should replace `rowObject.Name` to indexing like `rowObject[1]`.

Alternatively you can use `formatter: "dynamicLink"` which you can get from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913599/315935) for the example of the usage).