# How to add extra parameter in the base link url for jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I want to add an extra parameter in the jqgrid .  The below code is not working

```
 formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'loadHoldCode/id=?', addParam: '&customerId='+$('#custIdHidden').val()},
```

but If I hard code the parameter value, then the value is passed as I wanted.

```
 formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'loadHoldCode/id=?', addParam: '&customerId="123"},
```

Please help me what I should change or should I follow some other approach.

UPDATE:
using custom Formater, i have tried and still I am not seeing any link

```
    name: 'holdCode', 
    width: 100, 
    formatter:function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<a src="loadHoldCode/id=?&customerId=' + rowObject.customerId + '">' +
            cellvalue + "</a>";},                           
    searchoptions:{sopt: ['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']}, 
    sortable: true,
    editable: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `formatter` showlink, I would like to implement the usage of custom formatter.

If you have a hidden column as below, just construct the `src` yourself.

```
{ name: 'customerId', index: 'customerId', hidden: true },
{ name: 'link', index: 'link', title: false,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<a href="loadHoldCode/id=?&customerId=' + rowObject.customerId + '" target="_blank">' +
            cellvalue + "</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No I am not getting the hyperlink at all now

Comment: Do you encounter any Javascript error? Update your post with 'colModel' code.

Comment: If rowObject.customerId returns you 'undefined', then use rowObject[columnIndex] instead to get data from any column of a row. Updated my code as well to use href attribute in <a> tag.

Comment: I am still getting undefined for both Id and CustomerId, I am checking ,Thanks sir for the update

Comment: Let us know your whole colModel including this 'custIdHidden'. It will be a very useful information for us on helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to clear why your original code

```
formatoptions: {
    baseLinkUrl: 'loadHoldCode/id=?',
    addParam: '&customerId='+$('#custIdHidden').val()
},
```

can't work correctly. It means just that `formatoptions` property of the corresponding `colModel` item should be *initialized* with object with two properties `baseLinkUrl` and `addParam`. The value of both properties will be calculated **once** during the initialization. So you will have `$('#custIdHidden').val()` value **at the moment of creating the grid**.

It would be better to use the construction like

```
formatoptions: {
    baseLinkUrl: 'loadHoldCode/id=?',
    addParam: function () {
        return '&customerId=' + $('#custIdHidden').val();
    }
},
```

but it will work **only if jqGrid would be test whether the value of `addParam` is function or not. The formatter `"showlink"` don't test any from the options for the function (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L158) of jqGrid code). So **you can't use `formatter: "showlink"` to implement your requirement**.

I would suggest you to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913599/315935) the corresponding code example, where `$.param` supports properties as functions) or to use `formatter: "dynamicLink"` which you can download [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) (see `jqGrid.dynamicLink.js`). It's very simple and very flexible formatter. You can see more details and examples of usage of the formatter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236943/315935).

Comment: Hi Oleg, if i have to add a param that is part of a jqgrid row? is it possible then?

Comment: @user2375298: It's possible of cause and I suggested you some implementation options. If you want to use custom formatter, then the implementation should corresponds the **input data of the grid** which you use. You used `$('#custIdHidden').val()` in the original code. It meas that you wanted to place **the same value** in all cells of the columns. The value `rowObject.customerId` means that you have `customerId` property in every input item. So it means different values for every row. Moreover if you use `rowObject.customerId` and not `rowObject[12]` or some other syntax. It should be in data

Comment: @user2375298: Which format have input data from the grid? Could you provide test data (at least one row). If the format of data corresponds the usage of `jsonReader: {repeatitems: true}` or `xmlReader: {repeatitems: true}` then the syntax `rowObject.customerId` will be wrong. Which `datatype` you use ("json", "xml", "local", ...)? Do you use `loadonce: true` (in case of usage `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) or not? Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: I am using loadonce =true, and I am using Json Data. I am using a custom formatter function and When I try to access the value from rowdata, I get undefined .

Comment: @user2375298: **Which version of jqGrid you use? Which format have input data from the grid? Could you provide test data (at least one row).** `{"rows": [["a","b",123, null, true],...]}` are JSON data and `["rows": [{"customerId": "a", "col2": "b", "col3": 123, "col4": null, "col1": true}, ...]` are JSON data too, but the data should be read in different way.