# jqgrid creating a hyperlink with an id as the a parameter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a simple jqgrid.

`colModel: [ { name: 'CatId', index: 'CatId', width: 30, align: 'left' }, ...`

What I want to do is turn a column into a hyperlink like this example I find on google:

`formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit'}`

However I want to put the CatId as the parameter, eg:

```
formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=<CatId>'}
```

I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this, other than possibly just hooking into the loadcomplete event and going through and manually updating every row. Is there a nice way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The URL used by `formatter: "showlink"` will be constructed using `formatoptions` which could be `baseLinkUrl`, `showAction`, `idName` and `addParam`. The formatter `"showlink"` uses rowid (the id attribute of `<tr>` elements of the grid) for constructing the URL. The URL will be built as

```js
baseLinkUrl + showAction + '?' + idName + '=' + rowId + addParam
```

So the main problem is whether the value of `CatId` column be used or can be used as the rowid. If you would use `key: true` option to the definition of `CatId` column then jqGrid will use the value from `CatId` as rowid and you could use

```js
formatter: "showlink", formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: "someurl.php", idName: "action" }
```

If the value of `CatId` column can't be used as rowid then I would recommend you to use formatter: "dynamicLink" instead (see `jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js` [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins)). I described it in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935).