# jqGrid change formatter of cell when cell has no value

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a jqGrid in which one of the columns has set formatter as hyperlink below

```js
{ name: 'IDNumber', index: 'IDNumber', classes: 'hyperlink',
    search: true, stype: 'text',
    formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '#'} },
```

when a cell does not have `IDNumber` value I want to change the formatter to string .

The reason why I want to do is when cell has no value and having link as formatter it is not displaying the gridline

Comment: What you mean exactly under "when a cell does not have IDNumber value"? Is the value empty string, undefined or some other input data? Could you include exact data which you meanß

Comment: I mean when it is empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatter `showlink` produce `<a>` element for every input data which are strings (even empty string) or number.

I am not full sure that I understand correctly what you want.

If I understand you correctly you need to make the link "clickable" even if the cell contains *empty* string. To do so you can replace all empty strings in the column to something like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"`.

One more option which I can suggest you is to use my dynamicLink formatter which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935). It's very simple, but more powerful as predefined formatter `showlink`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyHyperlink.htm) shows how you can use it. The column

```js
{ name: "mylink", width: 60, sortable: false,
    formatter: "dynamicLink",
    formatoptions: {
        cellValue: function (cellValue, rowId, rowData, options) {
            return cellValue !== "" ?
                cellValue :
                "<span style='color:red'>empty link</span>";
        },
        url: function (cellValue, rowId, rowData) {
            return '/Store/AddToCart?id=' + rowId + '?' +
                $.param({
                    name: rowData.name
                });
        }
    } }
```

allows to define custom cell value and the URL used in the link. The source code of the formatter you can find [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins). The demo displays the grid

[image]

where I placed some custom text (red text "empty link") instead of empty string.