# Nice URL in JQGrid using a showlink formatter

Tags: jquery-ui, url, jqgrid, pretty-urls

I'm trying to get an URL of the form `http://xxxxx/application/sorting-plan-definition-edit/55555` (with 55555 the id of the row) in a JQGrid. I tried with a showlink formatter, but to no avail. If I do something like that:

```
formatoptions: {
    baseLinkUrl: contextPath + '/sorting-plan-definition-edit',
    idName: 'id'
},
```

I of course get an URL like `http://xxxxx/application/sorting-plan-definition-edit?id=555555`, which is not what I want. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) or to use `formatter: "dynamicLink"` which you can download [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) (the file `jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js`) and which I described initially in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935) (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236943/315935) too).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage, with a Javascript formatter function combined with a JSTL tag (as I work with a Java EE server):

```
"formatter": function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href='<c:url value="/sorting-plan-definition-edit" />/" + cellvalue + "'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```